# Deriving Time of extintion of a Small neural Network

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-process, neural-networks

I'm trying to derive the Expected Value of the Time of Extintion $\tau_{ext}$ of a small Neural Stochastic Network with the following dynamics, where I consider $\tau_{ext}$ to be the time of the last spike of the system.

Take $N=2$ the number of Neurons. $X_i(t)  $ represents the potential of Neuron $i$ at time $t$. Suppose $X(0) =(X_1(0),X_2(0))=(x,x)=(1,1) $ .

$X_i(t)=x e^{-t}$ , while there's no spike in the system. And when it is, say Neuron $j$ spikes, the value of neurons $i \neq j$ becomes $X_i(t)=x e^{-t}+C$ (I will take $C = 1\ \ a.e.$) and Neuron $j$ resets to $0$ potential. The dynamics restart afresh from the past, following the same deterministic behaviour as before, but with the new starting points, until the next spike of the system

The stochastic part comes with the time of the first spike the system. The first spike of Neuron $i$ when the initial condition is $X_i(0) = x $:

$\tau_i^x := inf\ \{t>0 : X_i(t)=0 \}$i.i.d.'s with law (in this particular case) $P(\tau_i^x >t)=e^{x(e^{-t}-1)} $

( Observe that $P(\tau_i^x =+ \infty)=e^{-x} > 0 $)

So the time of the first spike of the **system** is $\tau^x:=mín\  \tau_i^x$ with law $P(\tau>t)=e^{2x(e^{-t}-1)} $(in this case).

This would be a draft of the dynamics:[image: dynamics of the network]

And I'm thinking of $\tau_{ext}$ (in the case $x=1 , \tau:=\tau^1$ and $\hat{\tau}:=\tau^{x_{\tau}}$ ) as something like:
$$ \tau_{ext}= \tau \ \Bbb{1}_{\{\tau < +\infty \}}+ \hat{\tau}\ \Bbb{1}_{\{\tau < +\infty ,\ \hat{ \tau } < +\infty \}} + \sum_{i=1}^{G-1}{\tau_1^c(i)} $$ where $\tau_1^c(i) \sim \tau_1^c \ i.i.d. $ and $G\sim Ge(p := P(\tau_1^c = + \infty))$

Problems with this would be:

a) the second and "third" term seem difficult to compute.

b) I think I should modify the r.v's $\tau_1^c(i)$ so that  $P(\tau_1^c(i)=0,+\infty)=0 $ but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I didn't understand if your neural network is recurrent (has cycles) or not and what is your (stochastic) activation law from a neuron to its neighbors.

Comment: I've tried to clarify what you're asking by editing the post, is it clearer?

It does have cycles indeed; the times between renewals being $\tau^x$ 
And when a spike occurs ,say from neuron $i$, all other neurons receive an exitatory input $C ( = 1 \ \ a.e.) $

Comment: no, did you ever see a neural network ? look at https://www2.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/wtm/ps/icann98-2n.pdf page 2, $y_i(t)$ is the activation of the $i$th neuron and $w_{ij}$ are the weights or the (directed) connexions between neurons

Comment: Ok, now I understand better what you meant with " activation" and "cycles". This is not an Artificial Neural Network, but a biological one; and the model is a little different from the one you quoted

Comment: no it is not different every mathematical neural networks are of the form $y_i = f_i(w_{1i},\ldots w_{Ni},y_1,\ldots y_N)$ : it is the relation describing how the activation is propagated from a neuron to its neighbors !!! that these $f_i$ are stochastic functions or not doesn't change anything !